# Cribbage- 3of a kind lands on 31- how many points?

Tags: scoring, cribbage

When playing, player played a 3rd card for 6 points but also landed on 31.  How many points would they get?  6? 7? 8?

Answer (score 4):

**6** points for the third card of same rank.
**2** points for finishing at **31**.

**8** points total.

Wikipedia [Rules of cribbage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rules_of_cribbage) says

> If a card completes more than one scoring combination, then all combinations are scored.

and

> Card combinations cannot span a reset.

They can, though, complete the sequence.